# public variables on load (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

i defined some public variables in a class, when calling some variables in another class it works sometimes and sometimes not, the below code it works for the textbox but not in the form load, what i need is to run some sql sps to retrieve some data

```
    Imports PZ_Project.DBConnClass
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data


Public Class Main
    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim UserTypeID As String = DBConnClass.LogedinUserType
        MainMenu.Items.Add("Hi1")

        Dim UserMainMenu As New SqlCommand("User_Menu_Items_App")
        UserMainMenu.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        UserMainMenu.CommandText = "User_Menu_Items_App"
        UserMainMenu.Connection = Conn
        Dim UserTypeParam As SqlParameter = UserMainMenu.Parameters.Add("@intUserTypeID", LogedinUserType)
        Dim SQLUserTypeTableAdaptor As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(UserMainMenu)
        Dim SQLUserTypeDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
        SQLUserTypeTableAdaptor.Fill(SQLUserTypeDataSet)
        MessageBox.Show("1" & UserTypeID)
        For i = 0 To SQLUserTypeDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            MessageBox.Show(SQLUserTypeDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))
            MainMenu.Items.Add(SQLUserTypeDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
        Next

        ' Dim obj As Object = UserMainMenu.ExecuteScalar()
        'InitializeComponent()
        'Dim SelectMenuItems As String
        'Dim Menu_Item As String


        'Dim tsmi As New ToolStripMenuItem("Users", Nothing)
        'MenuStrip1.Items.Add(tsmi)


        'SelectMenuItems = "Select Distinct User_Types.Name From Users Inner Join User_Types on User_Types.ID = Users.User_Type_ID Where User_Name = '" + User_Name.Text + "'"
        'ConnCommand = New SqlCommand(UserName, Conn)
        'Dim SQLUserTypeTableAdaptor As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(ConnCommand)
        'Dim SQLUserTypeDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
        'SQLUserTypeTableAdaptor.Fill(SQLUserTypeDataSet)
        'For i = 0 To SQLUserTypeDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        '    UserType.Items.Add(SQLUserTypeDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
        'Next
        'UserType.Text = UserType.Items(0).ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseEnter
        TextBox1.Text = LogedinUserType
        MessageBox.Show(LogedinUserName & " / " & LogedinUserTypeName)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
 Dim UserTypeID As String = DBConnClass.LogedinUserType
```

to this

```
Dim DBConnClass As New DBConnClass
```

Add this

```
Dim UserTypeID As String= DBConnClass.LogedinUserType
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Tripodi, i tried this with no success, still working for the textbox and not working on the form load